# Bootstrap multi select buttons

Tags: c#, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor

In previously I use standard check-boxes, but now I want to use the bootstrap Multiple select boxes.

At this moment I can't see any rows in my drop down.

My new code:

```
<li>
<select href="#" class="selectpicker" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1" multiple data-selected-text-format="count">
   <option checked>&nbsp;@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => Model.AvailableCompanies[i].NAME)</option>
   <option name="selection[@i]" value="true"></option>
   <option name="ids[@i]" value="@Model.AvailableCompanies[i].ID"></option>
</select></li>
```

My previously code:

```
<li>
<a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabIndex="-1">
    <input type="checkbox" checked />&nbsp;@Html.DisplayTextFor(model => Model.AvailableCompanies[i].NAME)
    <input type="hidden" name="selection[@i]" value="true"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="ids[@i]" value="@Model.AvailableCompanies[i].ID" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C# we have cool helper and Multi select buttons

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Companies,
new MultiSelectList(Model.AvailableCompanies, "ID", "NAME", null),
    new
    {
    data_dropdown_align_right = "auto",
    id = "",
    data_selected_text_format = "count",
    data_actions_box = "true",
    @class = "selectpicker form-control",
    multiple = "multiple",
    data_live_search = "true"
    })
```